# MD5 or other Encryption in Silverlight C#

Tags: c#, encryption, silverlight-4.0, authentication, cryptography

I'm looking to encrypt a password field for use in a login system, therefore I would like to match encryption to make sure the user has entered the correct details.

For some reason Security.Cryptography doesn't have the MD5 services in Silverlight so I'm left looking for a different method.

I had used this before:

```
public string Md5Encrypt(string originalPassword)
        {
            //Declarations
            Byte[] originalBytes;
            Byte[] encodedBytes;
            MD5 md5;

            //Instantiate MD5CryptoServiceProvider, get bytes for original password and compute hash (encoded password)
            md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            originalBytes = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(originalPassword);
            encodedBytes = md5.ComputeHash(originalBytes);

            //Convert encoded bytes back to a 'readable' string
            return BitConverter.ToString(encodedBytes);
        }
```

But doesn't work now.

Can anyone give me a simple example for a working encryption method in Silverlight C#

Thanks

Comment: [MD5 has been broken](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/security/HackingMd5.aspx). It is **not** an encryption method. It is a hashing algorithm. Similar to MD5, [SHA1 should also be avoided](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2005/02/sha1_broken.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use Using HashLib in silverlight: http://hashlib.codeplex.com/ (look inside the HashLib.HashFactory.HashCryptoNotBuildIn namespace)

Also BouncyCastle.Crypt 1.7 release has a Silverlight 2.0 and above build where most crypto/hashing functions are available: http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/

And finally to your rescue, Mono source code is always here to rescue you: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Cryptography/SHA512Managed.cs which you can copy any cypto code to your project if it targets .NET 2.0 or above.